# pandas and calculate value of new column

Tags: pandas

I have pandas dataframe  with thousands columns and i want  to calculate new column 'future_calcs', that will contain the string - names of columns sorted their values and separated by commas. The content of this column will be used in another calculations.
Because of huge amount of columns i want to do all the calculations on pandas level.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(4,3)), columns['aaa','bbb','ccc'])

   aaa  bbb  ccc
0   70   27   32
1   15   27   4
2   51   17   37
3   95   27   88
```

I want to get

```
   aaa  bbb  ccc  future_calcs
0   70   27   32  aaa,ccc,bbb          <---  aaa > ccc > bbb
1   15   27   4   bbb,aaa,ccc
2   51   17   37  aaa,ccc,bbb
3   95   27   88  aaa,ccc,bbb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) for column names:

```
print ((np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)))
[[0 2 1]
 [1 2 0]
 [0 2 1]
 [0 2 1]]

print (df.columns[np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)])
Index([['aaa', 'ccc', 'bbb'], ['bbb', 'ccc', 'aaa'], ['aaa', 'ccc', 'bbb'],
       ['aaa', 'ccc', 'bbb']],
      dtype='object')

df['future_calcs'] = [', '.join(x) for x in df.columns[np.argsort(-df.values, axis=1)]]
print (df)
   aaa  bbb  ccc   future_calcs
0   70   27   32  aaa, ccc, bbb
1    4   27   15  bbb, ccc, aaa
2   51   17   37  aaa, ccc, bbb
3   95   27   88  aaa, ccc, bbb
```

Comment: That is exactly  what i need. Thx.  Hanz